# Who is the inventor of cyberpunk?

Tags: history-of, cyberpunk

Is there one person or creator cited as the inventor of cyberpunk?

Comment: If you want the grandfather of Cyberpunk, read "The Moon is a Harsh Mistress" by Heinlein.  It has almost all of the tropes in embryonic form.

Comment: @SteveED if you really think that, you should add an answer (that adduces some evidence!) so that people can consider it.

Comment: @AakashM - he asked for the inventor, not the grandfather.  i agree that Gibson is the inventor/father.

Comment: Brunner's "Stand on Zanzibar" is frequently (at least twice, anyway) cited as an early example. "Shockwave Rider" came a few years later, but still preceded Gibson by several years. Nothing against Gibson, but he was not the first.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The term "cyberpunk" is almost universally associated with William Gibson and, to a lesser extent, to some other authors; but Gibson didn't create this literary genre, end he even didn't create its *name*, which was first used by Bruce Bethke as a title for one of his short stories.

Cyberpunk (the genre, not the name) wasn't actually invented by any single person, but emerged from the works of various authors who contributed to its definition and evolution; Gibson was indeed one of its greatest expressions.

More info, as usual, at ["Cyperpunk" on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberpunk).

Comment: This answer is better than mine! It should be the definitive answer.

Comment: [Philip K. Dick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick) deserves some reference as well.

Comment: Bruce Sterling cannot be discounted when it comes to the origins of cyberpunk. His novel *The Artificial Kid* (1980) predates *Neuromancer* by 4 years and Gibson's first short story by a year.

Answer (score 17):

Bruce Bethke coined the word. Well-known editor Gardner Dozois popularized its use in connection with the kind of SF being pioneered in the early 1980s by Gibson, Sterling, etc.

Answer (score 10):

It should be noted that the [Vernor Vinge novella *True Names*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Names) (1981) pioneered many of the styles and concepts central to the idea of "cyberpunk" even if that term hadn't been invented yet.

Fully immersive virtual reality, anarchism, and early 1980s punk embellishments... all the elements are there.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean who invented it, William Gibson invented the term and what it is.

Comment: Any other answers will be summarily downvoted.

Comment: @Bill: is that a bad thing?

Comment: @J. Pablo: Not at all.  This is just the definitive answer to this question.  I'd lock the question if I could.  ;)

Comment: William Gibson didn't invent the term, even if he's universally recognized as the father of Cyberpunk. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberpunk

Comment: @Bill a truly definitive answer, while acknowledging William Gibson as the primary progenitor of the literary movement, wouldn't overlook the important contributions of several other key authors  - notably Neal Stephenson and Bruce Stirling in shaping the aesthetic as well.

Comment: @LessPop: He's not asking who influenced it.

Comment: @J. Pablo Fernández, Trying to claim Willian Gibson invented it is false. Populularised it perhaps, but certainly not invented. I distictly remember having many discussiins back in 1989/90 into what Cyberpunk was, in comparison with half a dozen authors who were using it, or writing in the genre. It was an organic evolution from other works, and wasn't in any way emergent as a standalone concept or entity. Simple evolution at work. Also when I look back at it, there was a whole number of author writing in that genre about dystopian futures, AI, convergent tech, before the term became popular.

Comment: @scope_creep: yeap, I've already pointed to the other answer as better.

Comment: Gibson coined the term "Cyberspace" (with the meaning we take from it today -- earlier authors used it differently), but although Neuromancer is associated with Cyberpunk, he didn't coin that phrase.

Comment: Don't forget the album by Billy Idol

Comment: Bruce Sterling was the main ideologist of the cyberpunk movement; I believe he even wrote a manifesto for the genre, and he edited the first cyberpunk anthology, *Mirrorshades*.. Of course, this happened after enough stories were written to make it a genre. But Sterlings very cyberpunky novel *The Artificial Kid* (1980) predates Gibson's first short story by 1 year and *Neuromancer* by 4 years,